Cannot filter variable in R - census data
I am working with large census data in R. I am narrowing down select population characteristics, and am trying to filter out the highest populations within a given country in a certain criteria.
Top populations determined using arrange(desc()). Few countries labelled as top.nativity.country, to make filtering easier. However, each attempt to filter() is producing a 0x3 table; that is, it's giving me an empty table.
For reference:
#rename columns 
names(nativity.roxbury) <- c("Nativity","Population Estimate", "Marigin of Error")
 
#Components Comparisson Suffolk
top.nativity.country <- c("Dominican Republic", "Cabo Verde","Jamaica","Haiti","Trinidad and Tobago", "Somalia","China")

nativity.roxbury %>% arrange(desc(`Population Estimate`)) %>% filter("Nativity" %in% top.nativity.country)

Data sourced from this US Census Bureau link.

yes youre right, i linked the wrong one - here is the appropriate data set https://data.census.gov/table?q=B05006&g=860XX00US02119

I solved the issue using the following code to check for any leading or trailing whitespace or case differences in the Nativity column.
Trim whitespace and convert to lower case
nativity.roxbury$Nativity <- str_trim(nativity.roxbury$Nativity)
nativity.roxbury$Nativity <- tolower(nativity.roxbury$Nativity)

Convert top.nativity.country to lower case
top.nativity.country <- tolower(top.nativity.country)

Filter after adjustments
filtered_data_nativity <- nativity.roxbury %>%
  arrange(desc(`Population Estimate`)) %>%
  filter(Nativity %in% top.nativity.country)

print(filtered_data_nativity)

